# Differentiation with summation in Lagrange multipliers

Tags: derivatives, lagrange-multiplier

I'm using the method of Lagrange multipliers.

Optimization problem is to maximize $$\begin{align} 
Q &= \sum_d  \sum_n \left[ \sum_z p(z|d,w_{dn}) \log p(z_{dn}) \\ 
+  \sum_z p(z|d, w_{dn}) \log p(d|z_{dn}) \\
+ \sum_z p(z|d, w_{dn}) \log p(w_{dn}|z_{dn})  \right] 
\end{align}$$
with respect to $p(d|z)$, subject to $\sum_d p(d|z) = 1$ for each $z$.

Lagrange function is $$H = Q + \sum_z \lambda_z \left(\sum_d p(d|z)-1 \right)$$

I'm now stuck at calculating ${\partial H}/{\partial p(d|z)}$.

For $Q$, I should focus on $\sum_z p(z|d, w_{dn}) \log p(d|z_{dn})$ and use $(\log(x))^{'} = 1/x$. Does $\partial Q / \partial p(d|z)$ become $$\frac{\partial Q }{ \partial p(d|z)} = \sum_d \sum_n \sum_z \frac{p(z|d,w_{dn})}{p(d|z_{dn})} \ \ ?$$

And for the second term, since $\partial \sum_d p(d|z) / \partial p(d|z)$ is $\sum_d 1 = d$, is it $\sum_z \lambda_z (d-1)$?

Comment: Do you really mean $H = Q + \sum_z \lambda_z \left(\sum_d p(d|z)-1 \right)$? Shouldn't the second term be zero when "$\sum_d p(d|z) = 1$ for each $z$"?

Comment: @Lovsovs Thanks for the comment. It should be. The basic idea is the same as [p.8 of this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.3900.pdf). In the middle, there is a Q-function denoted as $H$, and the last term also has $\sum_d (1- \sum_z p(z|d))$ (since I'm calculating a slightly different model, the notation is different)